# D3 Hive plot highlight Node and its links

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've been playing around with mbostock's D3 hive plot from [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2066415), and I would like to upgrade it to have similar functionalities as [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/RichMorin/raw/2117857/).  That is, when I mouseover a node, all its links should be highlighted, as well as text that shows from where and to where these links come from/go to.

I manage highlighting the individual nodes and links without a problem using for example

```
svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(lLinks)
.enter().append("path")
    .on("mouseover", function() {
        d3.select(this)
            .transition()
            .duration(150)
            .style("stroke-width", 3)
    })
```

but I am having trouble figuring out how to highlight all the links belonging to a particular node.

My current data structure is practically the same as [mbostock's](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2066415), which I assume is ill suited for what I am trying to do.

How should I go about upgrading this code to highlight all the links and show their source/destination?

Comment: im building a solution from mikes example, do you have an array of links with source/target like in his example?

Comment: Yes, I do.  But that may change in the future.  But your answer is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/boatrokr/rk2s5/

Below is the code for the node selection. As you can see, all I did was select the links and if the link source or destination matched the selected node, the stroke width of the link gets set to 5. I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, but it works. - edit: I forgot to remove a console.log in there - needed it for dev :)

```
svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + degrees(angle(d.x)) + ")"; })
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return radius(d.y); })
    .attr("r", 5)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.x); })
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
        d3.select(this)
            .transition()
            .duration(150)
            .style("stroke-width", 3)
        d3.selectAll(".link")
            .data(links)
            .style("stroke-width", function (dl) {
                if(dl.source == d){
                    console.log(dl);
                    return 5;
                }else if(dl.target == d){
                    return 5;
                }
        });
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(){
        d3.select(this)
            .style("stroke-width", 1.5)
        d3.selectAll(".link")
            .style("stroke-width", 1.5)
    });
```

Comment: Beautiful answer, thank you.  And this easily adaptable if I ever change my data structure.